# Setting contrasts for part of the factors in a model.matrix

Tags: r, lm, model.matrix

I have an experimental design to which I'd like to fit a linear regression model.

Here's the design `data.frame`:

```
design.df <- data.frame(batch=rep(c(1:3,1:3),4),
                      species=rep(c(rep("mouse",3),rep("rat",3)),4),
                      sex=rep(c(rep("M",12),rep("F",12))),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

`design.df$species` and `design.df$sex` are both `factors`:

```
design.df$species <- factor(design.df$species,levels=c("mouse","rat"))
design.df$sex <- factor(design.df$sex,levels=c("F","M"))
```

The contrast encoding of `design.df$species` should be `contr.treatment` whereas that of `design.df$sex` should be `contr.sum`.

To set it it as a `model.matrix` I thought perhaps this could work:

```
contrasts.list <- list(batch=NA,species="contr.treatment",sex="contr.sum")

design.mat <- model.matrix(as.formula(paste0("~",paste(model.factors,collapse="+"))),contrasts=contrasts.list,data=design.df)
```

Obviously it doesn't work according to the error I get:

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contrasts.arg[[nn]]) : 
  contrasts apply only to factors
```

So my question is how do I get the `model.matrix` from `design.df` according to the `contrasts.list` I specify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variable `model.factors` that's not defined anywhere. Not sure what the goal is. If you just wanted all these values as covariates, you can do

```
contrasts.list <- list(species="contr.treatment", sex="contr.sum")
design.mat <- model.matrix(~., contrasts=contrasts.list, data=design.df)
```

Note that your `contrasts.list` should only have values for the factor variables. Do not include `batch`.